# Cambiar el Texto Dibujado en un Canvas - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Me Volví a Interesar por JavaScript pero la Reanudar las Prácticas me Encontré con este Problema, ¿Es Posible lo citado en el Título? ¿O Debo Borrar el Texto y Escribirlo una y otra vez? (Por Ahora lo Reemplacé por una Alerta)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
        canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
        </style> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvasTest" width="600" height="600">
            Tu Navegador no Soporta Canvas.
        </canvas>
        <script>
        window.onload = function onLoadDoc() {
            var startScript = true; 
            if (startScript == true) {
                var puntos = 0;
                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasTest");
                var contextCanvas = canvasTest.getContext("2d");
                contextCanvas.font = "20px sans-serif";
                var textPuntos = contextCanvas.fillText("Puntos: " + puntos,canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
                canvas.addEventListener("click", function addPoint(){
                    puntos = puntos + 1;
                    // Aquí debería ir la Instrucción. 
                    alert("Puntos: " + puntos);
                });
            }
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sí, se puede. usas drawImage del contexto del canvas y le das como parámetro un ImageObject o algo similar. Revisa en mdn la documentación.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
        canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
        </style> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvasTest" width="600" height="600">
            Tu Navegador no Soporta Canvas.
        </canvas>
        <script>
        window.onload = function onLoadDoc() {
            var startScript = true; 
            if (startScript == true) {
                var puntos = 0;
                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasTest");
                var contextCanvas = canvasTest.getContext("2d");
                contextCanvas.font = "20px sans-serif";
                var textPuntos = contextCanvas.fillText("Puntos: " + puntos,canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
                canvas.addEventListener("click", function addPoint(){
                    puntos = puntos + 1;
                    // Aquí debería ir la Instrucción. 
                    //alert("Puntos: " + puntos);
// guardamos 
contextCanvas.save();
// limpiamos
contextCanvas.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
// actualizamos
var textPuntos = contextCanvas.fillText("Puntos: " + puntos,canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
//restauramos
contextCanvas.restore();
                });
            }
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```